# Is it a bad idea to explicitly ignore promises?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I have an api call which triggers an async function doSomething. Inside this function I have another async function that creates a notification for the user but I do not want to wait for it until it is finished. So I removed the await statement. The code works but is this a bad idea or bad practice because I get a "Missing await for an async function call" warning.

```
    public async createNotification(createdStuff: CreatedStuff): Promise<void> {
        const userNotification = new Notifcation(..);
        await userNotification.save();
    }

    public async doSomething(): Promise<CreatedStuff> {
        const createdStuff = await this.createStuff();
        await createdStuff.save();

        // here I removed the await statement
        this.notificationService.createNotification(createdStuff);

        return createdStuff;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `createNotification` return `void` instead of `Promise<void>`? So that you don't use `await` before `userNotification.save()`.

Comment: As general life advice I would say yes, it’s a bad idea. However, this might not apply here.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcq: Nope, it will still return a `Promise` as it is an `async` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `createLogPlayNotification(...)` rejects, you will run into an `unhandledRejection` [event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) which you probably don't want as it will crash your app depending on your NodeJS version (see [this link](https://nodejs.medium.com/node-js-v15-0-0-is-here-deb00750f278) for more information).

This does not mean you *have* to await it, you can simply add a `.catch`-handler on the returned promise:

```
// ..
this.notificationService.createLogPlayNotification(loggedPLay)
                        .catch(err => {
                            // do something with err, e.g. log it
                         });
return createdStuff;
```

Comment: thank you I see I need some more investigations about unhandled promise rejections but for now I added a catch block where I can log the error and the warning also disappeared